# How to retrieve JobId from Jenkins

Tags: go, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm doing a CLI in Go with [gojenkins](https://godoc.org/github.com/bndr/gojenkins). I need to run a build and then retrieve the job information (because then I want to wait till finish), but id retrieved by [BuildJob](https://godoc.org/github.com/bndr/gojenkins#Jenkins.BuildJob) method is not the same that [GetBuild](https://godoc.org/github.com/bndr/gojenkins#Jenkins.GetBuild) needs.

```
func RunPipeline(config *config.Profile) {
    jobName := "test_pipeline"
    jk, err := getClient(config)

    params := make(map[string]string)
    id, err := jk.BuildJob(jobName, params)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Build number: %d\n", id)

    build, err := jk.GetBuild(jobName, id)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Did not found build: %s\n", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(build)
}
```

Output:

```
Build number: 86
Did not found build: 404
<nil>
```

The last build id for that pipeline should be 37, but I got 86, can somoane helps me how to get that id? I didn't find anything on the lib documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I've found this [issue on github](https://github.com/bndr/gojenkins/issues/161). BuildJob's id is the id on the queue. So this works for me.

```
func Pipeline(config *config.Profile, buildData BuildData) {
    jobName := "test_pipeline"
    jk, err := getClient(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    queueId, err := jk.BuildJob(jobName, buildData.toParams())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    task, err := jk.GetQueueItem(queueId)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    retry := 0 
    for retry < 60 {
        if task.Raw.Executable.URL != "" {
            break
        }
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        task.Poll()
        retry++
    }

    build, err := jk.GetBuild(jobName, task.Raw.Executable.Number)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", build.Raw)
}
```